# Unit testing of method returning enum

Tags: junit, easymock

I am trying to create a test case of a method. Inside which another method is getting called which is returning an enum type.
How to expect and return for this method which is returning enum.

```
public class xyz {

    public request pqrs(Rest rest) { 
        Confirm cnf= new Confirm();
        cnf.getAct().toString();
    }
}
```

```
public class Confirm {

    public Hgs getAct() {
        return act
    }
}
```

```
public enum Hgs{

}
```

How to expect and return for getAct()?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please try to provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can understand and test your code more easy. Also a more detailed description would be good (e.g. I have no Idea what your mean by `How to expect and return for getAct()`, checking the returned result of the method maybe?)

Answer (score 0):

Returning an enum is like returning any other object. In your case, using EasyMock, it will look like:

```
Confirm confirm = mock(Confirm.class);
expect(confirm.getAct()).thenReturn(Hgs.VALUE);
replay(confirm);
```

However, the problem you will then have is that `Confirm` is create in the method, not injected. So using the mock is currently impossible. Two solutions there. The good one depends on your actual use-case.

1. Inject `Confirm`
2. Create it through some method that you can mock